# Why wont this work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to have this nav bar using `<ul>` and `<li>` and some css so that it makes a horizontal navigation but the way I have it, it doesn't work in IE, only Firefox and Chrome. Anyone know why?

Here is the CSS:

```
.navbar1 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.navbar1 li {
    float: left;
}
.navbar1 a {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FC0;
    background-color: #900;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    border-top-width: 5px;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #FC0;
    border-right-color: #FC0;
    border-bottom-color: #FC0;
    border-left-color: #FC0;
    font-family: "Britannic Bold";  
}
.navbar1 a:hover, a:active {
    background-color:#500
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no `.navbar1` in the HTML you provided.

Comment: @Richard - I successfully got it not to work by wrapping the `<ul>` with a `class="navbar1"` element, and IE8 in 7 compatibility mode. Normal IE8 works.

Comment: @Kobi - As did I, but the question is still incomplete without that information ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see all links on the right because each `<li>` still fills the whole width, even when floated.

Try this:

```
.navbar1 li {
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
}
```

You may want another `overflow: hidden;` here, just to be safe.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/kLRLv/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using float, why don't you use:

```
ul li {
 display: inline;
}
```

Then you can chose whether or not to specify a width and add margins & padding on the anchor tags to separate the items, and they will be places beside each other rather than having a line break in between them.

Answer (score 0):

Change the .navbar1 a { float: right } to .navbar1 a {float: none}

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the float: right in .navbar1 a style is causing the problem.

Also, you might want to put your menu ul into a div with a fixed width. Something like:

```
<div style="width: 95%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a></a></li>
       <li><a></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```